# Strange behavior when writing coordinates to an ESRI shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal, shapely

I am using python code straight out of the [GDAL/OGR Cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#create-point-shapefile-with-attribute-data) to write lat/lon coordinates (stored in a numpy array of tuples) to an ESRI shapefile like this:

```
#using almost entirely GDAL cookbook code here, 
#but have already done my affine transform

multipoint = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbMultiPoint)
for i in range(len(coordtrees)):
    point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
    point.AddPoint(coordtrees[i,0], coordtrees[i,1])
    multipoint.AddGeometry(point)



shpDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
if os.path.exists('points.shp'):
    shpDriver.DeleteDataSource('points.shp')
outDataSource = shpDriver.CreateDataSource('points.shp')
outLayer = outDataSource.CreateLayer('points.shp', geom_type=ogr.wkbMultiPoint)
featureDefn = outLayer.GetLayerDefn()
outFeature = ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
outFeature.SetGeometry(ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbMultiPoint))
outLayer.CreateFeature(outFeature)
outFeature = None
```

When I attempt to check the features (also pulled from the GDAL/OGR cookbook):

```
file = "/pathname/points.shp"

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

dataSource = driver.Open(file, 0)

if dataSource is None:
    print(f'Could not open {file}')
else:
    print(f'Opened {file}')
    layer = dataSource.GetLayer()
    featureCount = layer.GetFeatureCount()
    print(f"Number of features in {os.path.basename(file)}: {featureCount}")
```

I get back that I have 0 features in the .shp file (same when I view it in QGIS). However, when I rerun the first script, ceteris paribus, and check my features, I have my Multipoint file with one feature (that also displays in QGIS)! Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been bitten by a well known (but still very common cause of confusion) [GDAL/OGR Python "Gotcha!"](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas#Savingandclosingdatasetsdatasources).

You need to close your datasource so it gets written to disk *before* reading it again.

Change:

```
outFeature = None
```

To:

```
outDataSource = outLayer = outFeature = None
```